# Searching for a group of any repeating seven numbers in a row with Regex

Tags: regex

I'm wondering if there is a way to match a repeating group of any *seven digit* series of numbers using the regular expression. As in `1234567-1234567-1234567` or `8467905-8467905-8467905` would match all the numbers, but separate both of the *three seven digit* series as their own groups. How would you approach this problem?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with your edit. Do you want the three different occurrences to be in different groups in the match result. Why would you want that if they will be the same?

Comment: I probably just convoluted my point with the edit. Didn't notice your answer until I'd already done it. The solution works for me perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Back references](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html):

```
(\d{7})(-\1)+
```